# Does the infinite series $1/(n+1)$ diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series, harmonic-numbers

If so, how would one go about showing this? I'm playing around with comparison proofs and wondering if theres a way to show this either diverges or converges (due to it's very close relation to 1/n). Would it be correct to say it diverges due to the fact that as n approaches infinity, the +1 becomes negligible?

Comment: Do you mean series or sequence? That is kind of important! As a sequence it converges to $1$, as a series, $\sum_n (n+1)^{-1}$ diverges since the sequence is not a null-sequence.

Comment: write down the first few terms of the 1/(n+1) and 1/n series you were thinking about, and compare how they differ

Comment: Integral test. Very easy way to prove it diverges.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're right about the $+1$ becoming negligible as $n$ approaches infinity. There are a few good ways to see that this series diverges.

For one thing, it's actually the same series as $\sum \frac{1}{n}$, but with the first term missing. Since convergence or divergence has nothing to do with the initial terms, the two series must behave similarly.

---

Here's a way to use a direct comparison test:

We have $\frac{1}{n+1} > \frac{1}{2n}$ for all $n\geq 2$. This is good, because the series $\frac{1}{2n}$ is simply $\frac12$ times the series $\frac{1}{n}.$

---

The limit comparison test works very well. We just note that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1/(n+1)}{1/n}=1$, and therefore the two series either both converge or both diverge. Since $\frac{1}{n}$ diverges, then we're good

---

The integral test works, too. Calculate the integral: $\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x+1}$. Noting that it diverges, you can conclude that the corresponding series does, as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for the variety of ways to prove this, the integral test is something I'm a bit more confident with and you've just made it clear to me that it is the exact same series (just on step ahead!).

Answer (score 4):

It's just the $1/n$ sequence with one term deleted, so divergence is retained.

Answer (score 3):

**First way**

Observe that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac1{1+n}=\sum_{n=2}^{+\infty}\frac1{n}=+\infty
$$

**Second way**

Your observation about the presence of $+1$ is negligible when $n$ becomes huge is right: the formal way to use this is to observe that both
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac1{1+n}\;\;\;\mbox{and}\;\;\;
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac1{n}
$$
have positive terms, and since
$$
\lim_n\frac{\frac1n}{\frac1{1+n}}=1
$$
the two series have the same behaviour; and since the latter one diverges, so does the first one.

**Third way**
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac1{1+n}
&=\overbrace{\left(\frac12\right)}^{2^0 term}+\overbrace{\left(\frac13+\frac14\right)}^{2^1 terms}+
\overbrace{\left(\frac15+\frac16+\frac17+\frac18\right)}^{2^2 terms}+\\
&\cdots+
\underbrace{\left(\frac1{2^{k}+1}+\cdots+\frac1{2^{k+1}}\right)}_{2^k terms}+\cdots>\\
>&\overbrace{\left(\frac12\right)}^{2^0 term}+\overbrace{\left(\frac14+\frac14\right)}^{2^1 terms}+
\overbrace{\left(\frac18+\frac18+\frac18+\frac18\right)}^{2^2 terms}+\\
&\cdots+
\underbrace{\left(\frac1{2^{k+1}}+\cdots+\frac1{2^{k+1}}\right)}_{2^k terms}+\cdots=\\
=&\frac12+\frac{2}{2^2}+\frac{2^2}{2^3}+\cdots+\frac{2^k}{2^{k+1}}+\cdots\\
=&\frac12+\frac12+\frac12+\cdots=+\infty
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

Because $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}$ diverges, so does $-1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}$.  But $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n+1}=-1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}$ so this sum diverges as well.

Comment: I think you mean $-1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac 1n$...

Comment: Absolutely, thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "$+1$" becomes negligible and it is called the **Limit Comparison Test**. If $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = L \neq 0$$

then, $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ are both convergent or both divergent.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [cauchy condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test). The series in question converges iff the series
$$
\sum \frac{2^n}{2^n+1}
$$
converges. But the latter series diverges since the terms don't go the zero (the terms go to $1$). In particular, the series in question diverges.